# part II rake db:create problem

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

[image: The error]

Please help me guys. . .

OS: windows
Rails: 3.0.8

Comment: Very weird error, never seen before !!

Answer (score 0):

this problem is occurring because of latest version of libmyql.dll file in your Ruby/bin directory. Downgrade this. Means copy paste this file from older version of mysql.
or

you can download this file from the url below as a free download then extract the content and then copy paste libmysql.dll file to c:/Ruby/bin folder:

[libmysql.dll](http://www.dll-files.com/dllindex/dll-files.shtml?libmysql)

Comment: It looks a little dangerous to download a library from some site, other than the project's main location. How do you know the file is not infected with some malware?